# XAMPP authentication not working in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication, xampp

I have just installed XAMPP portable with Apache and MySQL.

I am trying to secure the main xampp directory that comes with XAMPP however it doesn't work, anyone can gain access to this directory? Here is my .htaccess file:

```
AuthName "xampp user"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "E:\xampp\PeterStuart_wst01\security\xampp.users"
require valid-user
```

Thanks,
Peter